# How to retrieve checkbox value in javascript for this code

Tags: javascript

How to retrieve the multiple checkbox value/label name in below code:

```
<input id ="abc" value="abeexch" type ="checkbox">
<input id ="nam" value="suns" type ="checkbox">
```

I want to get the value of another class name `xsw` if checkbox is selected.

Comment: <input id ="abc" value="abeexch" type ="checkbox">
<input id ="nam" value="suns" type ="checkbox">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [asl]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input[class='xsw']"), function(){            
            favorite.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
```